Is there a way to have either ReplyKeyboardButtons with callbacks, or InlineKeyboardButtons that write a message from the user and not the bot?
I'm working on a Telegram bot and I'm trying to implement a feature where the bot presents buttons to the user, and when the user clicks on a button, the bot should launch a defined function and echo the content of the button as a message from the user. I currently use InlineKeyboardButtons, implement the callbacks I want, and then in the callbacks have the bot reply "You answered: {clicked button text}" but this isn't really great UX.
Is there a way do do both? I've tried both ReplyKeyboardButtons and InlineKeyboardButtons, but I haven't found a way to make InlineKeyboardButtons write messages from the user's perspective rather than the bot's, or to have ReplyKeyboardButtons call callbacks.
My use case is that I have a screen that allows admins to send users of the bot messages with pre-defined response buttons. I want these response buttons to 1) send a message bubble from the user to the bot with their content and 2) trigger a callback. It seems I can only do 1 with ReplyKeyboardButtons and 2 with InlineKeyboardButtons.
Users may receive more than one message with buttons and reply in a different order compared to when they receive them so it's important that buttons and answers are linked to the messages sent.
If it's useful, I am using python-telegram-bot.

You're questions is unclear. Please simply what you're looking for. Are you just looking on how to let the Bot react to a specifi message?

@0stone0 My use case is that I have a screen that allows admins to send users of the bot messages with pre-defined response buttons. I want these response buttons to 1) send a message bubble from the user to the bot with their content and 2) trigger a callback. It seems I can only do 1 with ReplyKeyboardButtons and 2 with InlineKeyboardButtons, so I am asking if is there any way I can do both. I am adding this information to the main content.

ReplyKeyboardButtons just send the message, you can further process that message with a MessageHandler, try this
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters

async def start(update, context):
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['Message_1'], ['Message_2']])
    await update.message.reply_text("Choose", reply_markup=reply_markup)


async def message_handler(update, context):
    message = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text('You selected ' + message)
    
def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token("TOKEN").build()

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    
    # This handler processes any message sent by the user that starts with 'Message_'
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^Message_"), message_handler))

    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

main()

